# Selenium isn't waiting to click button before printing results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape results from Google Flights, using BeautifulSoup, *after* hitting a button that shows the full list of flights. I added an explicit wait, but for some reason this isn't working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/Shiva/Downloads/chromedriver")

driver.get('https://www.google.com/flights?hl=en#flt=/m/03v_5.IAD.2019-02-10*IAD./m/03v_5.2019-02-11;c:USD;e:1;sd:1;t:f')

xpath = '//*[@id="flt-app"]/div[2]/main[4]/div[7]/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/jsl/a[1]/span[1]/span[2]'

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,xpath)))

load_all_flights = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

load_all_flights.click()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

info = soup.find_all('div', class_="gws-flights-results__collapsed-itinerary gws-flights-results__itinerary")

for trip in info:
    price = trip.find('div', class_="flt-subhead1 gws-flights-results__price gws-flights-results__cheapest-price")

    if price == None:
        price = trip.find('div', class_="flt-subhead1 gws-flights-results__price")

    type_of_flight = trip.find('div', class_="gws-flights-results__stops flt-subhead1Normal gws-flights-results__has-warning-icon")

    if type_of_flight == None:
        type_of_flight = trip.find('div', class_="gws-flights-results__stops flt-subhead1Normal")

    print(str(type_of_flight.text).strip()  + " : " + str(price.text).strip())
```

Comment: My guess is that the button is handled with javascript, try waiting for the new page to load before retrieving the html

Comment: I would suggest using implicit waits to make sure that the page is able to load the new content after the click before you try to get it